# Dynamic report in MS access will not update with source query

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

So I have a database of mechanical components. I have a search form in the database that allows the user to apply filters to a query (through the use of 5 text/combo boxes and an "apply filters" button). This query will contain the components that made it past the filter, and some details about those components.  Also on the search form, I have a sub-report that is bound to the query.

My plan is to have the user filter though the data using the controls on the form. As the user filters out components, the report should update to display what components pass the new query. They would then select the component they are interested in by clicking on a record in the report, and that component ID would be passed into VBA to do more stuff.

My problem is that the report bound to the query will not update as the query does.  I have tried using DoCmd.Requery and Me.Form.Refresh on the button click event, but haven't gotten anywhere. It only works if I close the form, then re-open it.

**How do I get my bound report to change dynamically as the user modifies the SQL of its source query?**

Here's my click event code:

```
Private Sub cmdApplyFilters_Click()
Call updateSearchFilters
Me.Requery
Me.Form.Refresh
End Sub
```

Here's my sub to update the query:

```
Public Sub updateSearchFilters()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim searchQryDef As DAO.QueryDef

strSQL = searchSQLstrBuilder(Forms("frmSearch").tboCompID, Forms("frmSearch").tboDesc, Forms("frmSearch").cboType, Forms("frmSearch").cboVendor, Forms("frmSearch").tboVendPN)
Set searchQryDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySearchRes")
searchQryDef.SQL = strSQL
End Sub
```

Here's my SQL string builder:

```
Public Function searchSQLstrBuilder(tboCompID As TextBox, tboDesc As TextBox, cboType As ComboBox, cboVend As ComboBox, tboVPN As TextBox) As String
searchSQLstrBuilder = "SELECT tblDocs.compID, tblComponents.Desc, tblComponents.type, tblComponents.vend, tblComponents.vendorPN "
searchSQLstrBuilder = searchSQLstrBuilder & "FROM tblComponents INNER JOIN tblDocs ON tblComponents.numComp = tblDocs.numComp "

Dim strCompID, strDesc, strType, strVend, strVPN As String
strCompID = tboCompID.Value
strDesc = tboDesc.Value
strType = cboType.Value
strVend = cboVend.Value
If IsNull(tboVPN.Value) Then
    strVPN = ""
    searchSQLstrBuilder = searchSQLstrBuilder & "WHERE (((tblDocs.compID) Like '*" & strCompID & "*') AND ((tblComponents.Desc) Like '*" & strDesc & "*') AND ((tblComponents.type) Like '*" & strType & "*') AND ((tblComponents.vend) Like '*" & strVend & "*') AND ([vendorPN] Is Null Or (tblComponents.vendorPN) Like '*" & strVPN & "*'));"
Else
    strVPN = tboVPN.Value
    searchSQLstrBuilder = searchSQLstrBuilder & "WHERE (((tblDocs.compID) Like '*" & strCompID & "*') AND ((tblComponents.Desc) Like '*" & strDesc & "*') AND ((tblComponents.type) Like '*" & strType & "*') AND ((tblComponents.vend) Like '*" & strVend & "*') AND ((tblComponents.vendorPN) Like '*" & strVPN & "*'));"
End If

End Function
```

Thanks in advance!  Let me know if there's more information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand this problem, because you can't have a button on a report.  They're not interactive.  So, I'm assuming you have a button on a form which *opens* a report.

What you might try is updating the RecordSource of the report.  After the updateSearchFilters code runs, at the very end of that function, add:

```
Reports!rptMyReport.RecordSource = "Select * from qrySearchRes"
```

Alternatively, you could have a SQL string as a RecordSource and pass variables in using OpenArgs:

```
Dim strMyValue As String
strMyValue = "This Is A TEST!"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMyReport", acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal, strMyValue
```

and then in the report you would add this on Form_Load:

```
Dim strMyValue As String
strMyValue = Me.OpenArgs
```

Then you can use strMyValue as a parameter in your RecordSource.

It is also possible to pass **multiple** values via OpenArgs, but it's a little more tricky.  You can use a pipe delimiter ("|") to separate your values, but when you open it you'll have to parse out the values on the other side using some VBA.

Comment: To clarify, the form contains the button and text/combo boxes. It also has a sub-report on the form that is meant to display the query results.  Reports don't have buttons, but their cells do have "on click" events, so I wanted to use that to select the desired component.  Unfortunately neither of your suggestions worked. I think my problem may be something to do with the "LIKE" operator in SQL.  I can't find a good way to pass a variable string to it. I'm finding the report works if there are no LIKEs in the source query SQL. Any thoughts?

Comment: You were right the first time, I needed to reset the record source.  I just needed to bang my head into the wall a few times before I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of unusual to have a subreport on a form...
After running `updateSearchFilters`, you need to explicitly Requery the subreport.

```
Me!subReport.Report.Requery
```

`subReport` is the name of the subreport control on the form.